# How could I start envoy from a dumped config. Which is generated by /config_dump

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

When debug envoy, I try to run from a dumpped config file, but couldn't figure it out.

Dump the config using the [envoy admin api '/config_dump'](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.12.2/operations/admin#get--config_dump).

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:15000/config_dump -o envoy.config
```

But can't start it up, there are errors:

```
envoy --config-path envoy.config
...
[2019-12-22 12:40:50.313][194][critical][main] [external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:98] error initializing configuration 'envoy.config': Protobuf message (type envoy.config.bootstrap.v2.Bootstrap reason INVALID_ARGUMENT:configs: Cannot find field.) has unknown fields
[2019-12-22 12:40:50.313][194][info][main] [external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:607] exiting Protobuf message (type envoy.config.bootstrap.v2.Bootstrap reason INVALID_ARGUMENT:configs: Cannot find field.) has unknown fields
```

Answer (score 5):

The dumped config is actually not intended to be used to start up the server.  You start a server with a [Bootstrap Config](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/config/bootstrap/v2/bootstrap.proto), but if you look closely at the output of the `/config_dump` endpoint, it actually contains 5 or more separate config dumps.  My local envoy (Envoy 1.12.2) actually show config dumps for:

- Bootstrap Config
- Clusters
- Listeners
- ScopedRoutes
- Routes
- Secrets

You can read more about the output structure in the config dump [docs](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/admin/v2alpha/config_dump.proto#admin-v2alpha-configdump), but the summary of that is that it's a totally different structure.

If you do take the output of `/config_dump` and strip it down to just the bootstrap config field, you can indeed start the server with it.